# Program crashes on VM just when finishing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, samtools

I am running `samtools` on a google VM with 8CPUs. It seems that when the process is finished, the program crashes giving the below error. At the same time, there is a problem with the bucket, showing this. Any ideas? Problems with saving the file?

Error:

```
username@instance-1:~/my_bucket$ /usr/local/bin/bin/samtools view -@20  -O sam -f 4 file_dedup.realign
ed.cram > file.unmapped.sam
samtools view: error closing standard output: -1
```

Also this comes up when tying ls in the bucket directory:

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your use case. Are you using FUSE to mount your bucket to the VM instance?

Comment: bucket is mounted using: /usr/bin/gcsfuse username_bucket_1 my_bucket

Comment: Have you tried to save your data at the VM's disk instead of bucket?

Comment: Don't think I have enough space on the VM. The output file is about 6GB. How would I specify that the files is saved to the VM and not the bucket?  I thinks its related to big files, because copying small files within the bucket   is OK.

Comment: This issue could be related to [differences FUSE from a POSIX file system](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes).  You can try to set path for file.unmapped.sam.

Comment: should I set the path to the bucket?

Comment: No, the idea is to check if it'll work with VM's disk instead of bucket. If there's no issue, so the problem is FUSE.

Comment: It worked when linking to the VM disk instead. Is there a reason why I should use a bucket at all? Can I Just increase the size of the VM disk and use that? Are costs the same and is there a max size limit?

Answer (score 1):

As we discovered at the comment section this issue is related to the [difference between a FUSE and a POSIX file systems](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes).

You can solve this issue in two ways:

1. Increase disk space on your VM instance (by following the documentation [Resize the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/working-with-persistent-disks#resize_the_disk) and [Resize the file system and partitions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/working-with-persistent-disks#resize_partitions)) and stop using Google Cloud Storage Bucket mounted via FUSE.
2. Save data received from `samtools` to the VM's disk at first and then move them to the Google Cloud Storage Bucket mounted via FUSE.

You can estimate cost for each scenario with [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Keep in mind that persistent disks have [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdnumberlimits), among them:

> - Each persistent disk can be up to 64 TB in size, so there is no need to manage arrays of disks to create large logical volumes.
> - Most instances can have up to 128 persistent disks and up to 257 TB of total persistent disk space attached. Total persistent disk space
>   for an instance includes the size of the boot persistent disk.

In addition, please have a look [Quotas & limits for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas).

Comment: Thanks. It seems I am limited to 250GB om my VM

Comment: You can increase disk  space if needed. Please upvote/accept my answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: @user2300940 Your account quota is probably limited to a total of 250 GB for persistent disks. https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas